# exposition in dplyr without magrittr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Does dplyr have a preferred syntax for magrittr's %$% operator, since this is not loaded by default in the tidyverse? For example, I often use this:

```
data.frame(A=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5),B=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5)) %$% chisq.test(A,B)
```

Is there a preferred way to do this within the tidyverse alone? I feel like pull() should be able to do this, but I can't figure out how to call pull() twice inside the pipe.

Comment: [`magrittr`](http://magrittr.tidyverse.org/) is part of the tidyverse, it just isn't one of the packages loaded using `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: @KevinArseneau so your solution is "if you want to use `%$%`, do `library(magrittr)`"

Comment: @Spacedman, my comment wasn't really intended to be a solution, I think others have done a good job of that. But I think it was worth clarifying that the meta-package is not the limit of the tidyverse and indirectly, yes, `library(magrittr)` works just fine. I am favouring the curly brace approach though I'm not fond of `.$x` versus the bare column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dot `.` to refer to the original dataframe, and use curly braces `{}` to prevent `%>%` filling in the first argument:

```
data.frame(A=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5),B=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5)) %>% 
    {chisq.test(.$A, .$B)}
```

Comment: Why not use `library(magrittr)` and then use the `%$%` pipe?

Answer (score 4):

From vigenettes of [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html):

> The “exposition” pipe operator, `%$%` exposes the names within the
>   left-hand side object to the right-hand side expression. Essentially,
>   it is a short-hand for using the with functions.

So you could do it with `with`:

```
data.frame(A=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5),B=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5)) %>% with(chisq.test(A,B))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Marius solution, there is an option with `summarise` if we need to extract only the `p-value`

```
 set.seed(24)
 data.frame(A=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5),B=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5)) %>% 
         summarise(p_val = chisq.test(A, B)$p.val)
 #     p_val
 #1 0.8394397
```

Suppose, we need to get other parameters, then use `broom::tidy`

```
set.seed(24)
data.frame(A=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5),B=rbinom(100,1,p=0.5)) %>% 
    summarise(p_val = list(broom::tidy(chisq.test(A, B)))) %>%
    unnest
#  statistic   p.value parameter                                                       method
#1 0.0410509 0.8394397         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
```